# How to store a big boolean list in a JSON file?

Tags: json, serialization, boolean

i'm using a boolean array in memory to store a collision map of this size : 16*16*14*16 = 57344 booleans . And i must store it in a json file for 50 different maps.I've been searching for the best way to store it in my json file:

- Compress all the json document in base64 or other encoding
- Try to compress in a better readable way the collisionMap what is the big part

In my try of doing this (but maybe i'm reinventing the wheel) i've made this example:

> 000111101111111111100000000001111000
>
> 0_3_4_1_11_10_4_3
>
> the first number point that starts with a 0 , and the next number
>   means that there is 3 zero , nest to it 4 ones , 1 zero ...

Maybe with this you can't see too much problem , but with 57344 booleans can be still  big is there is many variation.

but i don't know if there is another better way to store it .

Any idea if there is a good solution?

Comment: convert bool no into hexa no. And then transfer that as string ? :O

Comment: jashwant 57344 / 16 = 3584 still being very long

Comment: jashwant , your solution is still bigger than mine ones cause you must serialize all strings also with 0. Make a test , you'll see.

Comment: convert to base 36 and then use gzip to compress the string?

Comment: Hello! Do you find answer for you question?